# Why $BASH_SUBSHELL doesn't work with /bin/bash shebang

Tags: bash, shebang, subshell

Doing some tests, I discovered that setting the bash shebang in a script would cancel the $BASH_SUBSHELL behavior.

```
# in the terminal
$ echo $BASH_SUBSHELL
0
$ (echo $BASH_SUBSHELL)
1
```

script_no_shebang.sh

```
echo $BASH_SUBSHELL
```

```
$ ./script_no_shebang.sh
0
$ test=$(./script_no_shebang.sh)
$ echo $test
1
```

script_shebang.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $BASH_SUBSHELL
```

```
$ ./script_shebang.sh
0
$ test=$(./script_shebang.sh)
$ echo $test
0
```

Any idea if this is a bug or an expected behavior ?

I tried several combinations as tested above. Using a lot of bash functions I don't see myself removing the shebang to use $BASH_SUBSHELL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the script starts with a shebang, the operating system kernel executes the shebang as a command, with the script name as its argument. So it's equivalent to running

```
/bin/bash ./script_shebang.sh
```

This starts a new `bash` process that initializes the subshell level to `0`.

When there's no shebang, the shell executes the script itself in a subshell, so it increments the subshell level.

You can see the equivalent of the shebang if you do

```
test=$(/bin/bash ./script_no_shebang.sh)
```

Basically, starting a new `bash` instance is not the same as a subshell.

Comment: Thank you, I will validate your answer. Any idea how to bypass this behavior, so I could detect if I am executing my script in a subshell or not ?

Comment: Use an environment variable that you increment yourself, not a variable that's counting something different from what you want.

Comment: Note that not all shells do this. `bash` and `ksh` do. `zsh` and `dash` will fork `sh` to execute the script instead. `fish` just reports an error.

Comment: Moral of the story: if your script is expected to be executed by `bash`, make sure it has a shebang or you explicitly execute the script with `bash`.

Comment: @chepner But their problem is that using the shebang gives them the result they don't want.

Comment: If this is anything more than curiosity over an unexpected difference, I suspect they aren't using `BASH_SUBSHELL` correctly.

Comment: @chepner Clearly. They expect any nested shell to be a subshell. See my earlier comment about what they should actually be doing.

Comment: To precise further, I want to control the script output depending on whether it is called directly by the user, or if it is populating a variable.

Comment: Maybe what you really care about is whether the output is being displayed on a terminal or not? Use `if [ -t 1 ]` to test if stdout is a terminal

Comment: Thank you, I included this behavior in the last ```yb```version.